# PythonTeX + \InputIfFileExists for inputting rows in longtable creates spurious space before the end

Tags: tables, longtable, pythontex

TeX Live 2014 on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\chapter{longtable with \\InputIfFileExists vs. longtable without}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    \InputIfFileExists{tablerows.tex}{}{}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    {John Doe} & {110} \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Contents of file `tablerows.tex` (contains final newline):

```
{John Doe} & {110} \\
```

Removing `\usepackage{pythontex}` gives the same output in both cases. This appears to be a bug, but I would like to find workarounds. I have not found anything on this issue asking a search engine. Any ideas? Am I missing anything?

PS: Might also affect other tables/tabulars, I have not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `pythontex` requires, among other packages, `filehook` which is the bad guy in this case. The definition of `\InputIfFileExists` becomes

```
\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}
    {\expandafter\filehook@swap\expandafter{\@filef@und}{%
       #2\@addtofilelist{#1}%
       \filehook@every@atbegin{#1}%
       \filehook@atbegin{#1}\@@input
     }%
     \filehook@atend{#1}\filehook@every@atend{#1}%
    }%
}
```

whereas the original definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1757:
\newcommand\InputIfFileExists[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {#2\@addtofilelist{#1}\@@input \@filef@und}}
```

This means that after the trailing `\\` in the input file, some actions are performed which stop TeX from searching for `\omit` or `\noalign` and so, since the table has not yet ended, to start a new row.

Workaround: define a table safe command using the original `\InputIfFileExists`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{filehook@csuse}
  {\let\TablesafeInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists}% filehook is not loaded
  {\let\TablesafeInputIfFileExists\latex@InputIfFileExists}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\chapter{longtable with \\InputIfFileExists vs. longtable without}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    \TablesafeInputIfFileExists{kreuvrows.tex}{}{}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    {Col 1} & {Col 2} \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    {John Doe} & {110} \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]